# Source Code for Calling Multiple in ASP.NET MVC 2.0(ASPX Engine) Actions on a Link which is bound to Telerik MVC Grid Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

I  need a Source Code for Calling Multiple in ASP.NET MVC 2.0(ASPX Engine)  Actions on a Link which is bound to Telerik MVC Grid Column.

I am using Entity Framework , Linq to Entities , ASP.NET MVC 2 , Repository pattern and ASPX ViewEngine .

I have a Telerik MVC Grid Column as Status . This column is bound to a ClientTemplate ( ActionLink Format) as " View " . When a user clicks on " View " .

Multiple Telerik MVC Grids which showing 
1. Problem Log  . ( Visible only if Status is " Account is in Error" otherwise show last Cleared Problem ( Problem text and Problem Description coming from DB, Can be shown only in a TextBox(problem Name,) " In error" and a div " description of Problem" )

1. Status History .
2. Bank account information for logged User
3. Admin Information

should be displayed ..

from Status Grid Column I am fetching a Bank Account Number and my Status is coming from another table ..

now my problem is that how to call multiple actions present in my controller ( with conditions ) ?

Can anybody guide me with working code if any ?:(

if possible mail me on ashes22@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When view is clicked you want to show a new view that contains then calls to other action methods in your controller(s) or other views.

So for example when you click on the View link on the grid, you would then have the view link go to another Route (and in turn another controller).
So lets say the "view" link brings you to a controller named
CombinedStatusController

Then in your /Views/CombinedStatusController/Index.aspx
you call RenderAction to call a method on each controller here Im assuming named StatusController, BankAccountController, AdminInformationController each with a method:
public ActionResult Index(int statusId)...

<%=Html.RenderAction("Index", "Status", new { statusId = statusId} ) %>

<%=Html.RenderAction("Index", "BankAccount", new { statusId = statusId} ) %>

<%=Html.RenderAction("Index", "AdminInformation", new { statusId = statusId} ) %>

Each one of those actions would then return a view with a telerik grid in it.
So you have three separate views that are getting created by calling one parent view of CombinesStatusController.

Now - another option instead of Html.RenderAction is Html.RenderPartial. The difference is RenderPartial goes directly to a view (without going through your controller) and passes over a copy of the current model to it. In your case you need to retrieve data specific to a statusId so I would not use RenderPartial here but RenderAction.

Hope this helps a bit : )

Comment: I want to show same View but only thing is that WHEN SOMEONE Filters my previous Grid then that Grid should be displayed ... then when someone clicks a link in my filtered Grid an another Grid which is showing the details should be displayed on same View  while my Filterable  Master Grid should be also visible ....

Answer (score 0):

You don't call multiple Actions from the front-end.  You call one and have that one call other Action (or non-Action) methods within the Controller.

Comment: But how to call another action in my action ? I am a total fresher in ASP.NET MVC .. dont know how this thing works

Comment: what is the difference between Action and NonAction

Comment: Not much of a difference - a method is a method is a method.  It's an Action method when its return type is ActionResult or something derived from ActionResult (e.g. JsonResult).  Check out this Inheritance Hierarchy to see all that derive from ActionResult - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx

Comment: So one Action method can call another Action method just as easily as any non-Action method.  Just make sure that if A calls B, that A expects B to return ActionResult and knows what to do with it.

Comment: 'code'[HttpPost]      
         [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _GetStatus(string statusID)
            {
            EnrollStatusViewModel model = new EnrollStatusViewModel();
           if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusID))
                {
                model = this.workerService.GetEnrollViewModel();
                return new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new SelectList(model.GetStatus, "Status", "Status",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)                    };}